# Time Series forecasting feature creation/engineering

Tags: time-series, feature-engineering, forecasting, feature-construction

I'm new to time-series-forecasting and was wondering, whether in a single variable forecast e.g.: X -> Y the creation of additional features of X leads to an improvement when training.
So if adding features like month, day-of-week, rolling mean or lagged series from X does improve Statistical models (Arima, Exponential Smoothing), Tree based models (XGB, Random Forest) or neural networks. These features would be fully correlated with X, so does it help, make predictions worse or have no effect?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most tree-based models are not a good fit for time series forecasting. I'm not aware of any truly tree-based models that extrapolate outside of the training data as is required for forecasting.

As for the other models you mention, better input features for the particular application will result in better model performance. What makes a "better" features is extremely application dependent. I have used rolling moments with good success in a forecasting application.

Typically ARIMA and exponential smoothing models are univariate. In fact, every state space model (which exponential smoothing models fall under) has an ARIMA equivalent. The same can be said of their multivariate extensions (see Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing: the State Space Approach by Rob Hyndman). I bring up the fact they are univariate because your question seems like you want to feed multiple features to your model.

Features built from a time series do not need to be "fully correlated" with the time series as you say. As an example a transformation from time to something cyclic in time like day of the week or month will not be "fully correlated" with the original input.

Comment: Tree-based models can be used for forecasting if you reformat the data by [windowing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#data_windowing), just as you would for neural networks, and can be very powerful for forecasting.

Comment: I see your point. However, I'm still not aware of any tree based models (except for model trees) that are capable of extrapolating outside the range of response variables seen in the training data. A traditional forecasting problem like "given a history of car sales by month, predict car sales for each of the next 12 months" would usually desire that behavior, especially when there is a positive trend in sales. ARIMA and exponential smoothing models can both handle that case, but I'd expect the tree models to predict the maximum value seen in the training set for the next 12 months.